# What is the shortcut to hide the navigator view in Apple Keynote?

Tags: shortcut, keynote

I want to show only the slide, without the left-side slide thumbnails in the Navigator View. How can this view be made hidden?

I am on Keynote version 7.3.1 (5249)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that **Navigatior View** is designed to show the thumbnails for navigation.  **Slide Only** view shows only the slide without the thumbnails.

There is no built in shortcut to change views.  However, a custom keyboard shortcut can be added in the **System Preferences**.

**To create a shortcut:**

- Go to **System Preferences**
- **Keyboard**
- **Shortcuts** Tab
- Select **App Shortcuts** in the left pane
- Click the Plus button
- Set **Application** to Keynote from the dropdown
- Type the Menu command EXACTLY as it appears in the menu
- Choose a key combination

Now you can change view with custom shortcut.

---

#### Adding custom shortcut:

[image: Custom Keyboard Shortcut]

---

#### Switching views:

[image: switching views]

Comment: Excellent! You can use this to set up all sorts of shortcuts. I have several for positioning objects. Cheers!